# Globals Updating During Var assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global

The problem that I am have is when I run a function and then assign variables of  the data for some reason updated my global every time. I do not see where in my code I am calling for my global to update. Is there something I am missing ?

```
var newInputs = $scope.configurationMap['RDY2000'].configuration.inputs.universalOffsets;
$scope.rdyInputs = function(){

    var input = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < newInputs.length; x++) {
        if (newInputs[x].sensorType) {
            input.push(newInputs[x])
        }
    }   
    return input
}

if($scope.data.property = 'rdy2000'){
    $scope.inputs = $scope.rdyInputs($scope.data);
    var Test = configUtilService.getOnlyCts(inputsKeyList)
    var counter = Test.length + 1;
    var tether = $scope.originalData.tether[0];

    for (var x = 0; x < $scope.inputs.length; x++) {
        $scope.data.inputs[x] = $scope.inputs[x]
        $scope.data.inputs[x].key = 'CT' + counter;
        $scope.data.inputs[x].type = 'ct';
        $scope.data.inputs[x].description = tether +  $scope.inputs[x].description;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is a share by reference language. When a function changes the contents of an object, all code which has a copy of the reference will see those changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `rdyInputs` function needs a parameter:

```
̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶r̶d̶y̶I̶n̶p̶u̶t̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶)̶{̶
$scope.rdyInputs = function(newInputs){

    var input = [];

    for (var x = 0; x < newInputs.length; x++) {
        if (newInputs[x].sensorType) {
            input.push(newInputs[x])
        }
    }   
    return input
}
```

Don't use a global variable; use a parameter.